# UIDatePicker sizing in iPhone

Tags: ios, iphone, ipad, xamarin.ios, uidatepicker

I'm trying to show an UIDatePicker when the user taps on an UITextField.
On iPad I've used this code and works wonderful but on iPhone the UIDatePicker gets cut.
This is my code

```
UIBarButtonItem btnCancel;
UIBarButtonItem btnFlexibleSpace;
UIBarButtonItem btnDone;
UIBarButtonItem[] btnItems;
btnCancel = new UIBarButtonItem(UIBarButtonSystemItem.Cancel, KBToolbarButtonDoneHandler);
btnFlexibleSpace = new UIBarButtonItem(UIBarButtonSystemItem.FlexibleSpace, null);
btnDone = new UIBarButtonItem(UIBarButtonSystemItem.Done, pickerDoneHandler);
btnItems = new UIBarButtonItem[] { btnCancel, btnFlexibleSpace, btnDone }; 
myToolbar.SetItems(btnItems, true);

UIDatePicker dpPurchaseDate;
dpPurchaseDate = new UIDatePicker(new RectangleF(0,44,this.View.Bounds.Width,216));
dpPurchaseDate.Mode = UIDatePickerMode.Date;
dpPurchaseDate.MaximumDate = NSDate.Now;
dpPurchaseDate.TimeZone = NSTimeZone.LocalTimeZone;
dpPurchaseDate.UserInteractionEnabled = true;
dpPurchaseDate.BackgroundColor = UIColor.White;

UIView pDateView;
pDateView = new UIView (new RectangleF (0, 0, this.View.Bounds.Width, 260));
pDateView.AddSubview (myToolbar);
pDateView.AddSubview (dpPurchaseDate);
evaluationDate.InputView = pDateView;
```

On iPad it looks like this.
[image: iPad Image]

In the iPhone it looks like this
[image: iPhone Image]

Any ideas on why this happens?

Comment: My answer should have worked for you. Please mark my answer as correct.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You create your `UIDatePicker` without setting any resizing masks or auto layout constrains to auto-adjust its frame, so by default it will just keep its size regardless of its superview.

---

The easiest way to handle autoresizing is setting `UIView`'s `autoresizingMask`:

```
dpPurchaseDate.autoresizingMask = (UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleWidth |     // Grow horizontally
                                   UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleTopMargin); // Keep at the bottom of the superview
```

You can experiment with resizing using Interface Builder.

Comment: How can I set the auto constrains? I'm really new in Monotouch and this is far beyond my comprehension.

Comment: Sure. On iOS you should always prefer Interface Builder for any UI work, especially with all the upcoming screen sizes.

Answer (score 1):

Try adding this to force a resize of your picker views

```
for (UIView * subview in dpPurchaseDate.subviews) {
        subview.frame = dpPurchaseDate.bounds;
    }
```

If that doesn't work, assign `this.View.Bounds.Width` to a float and see what the value is. Maybe it's set to a landscape width for some reason.

Comment: Still nothing. I tried on two devices and the simulator. On all of them the reported Width is 320.

Answer (score 0):

There are two solutions to reach the goal.

1. Create two .xib files for iphone and ipad then add require objects there with frame according to iphone screen and map them.
2. Programmatically manage the frame of pickerview and other objects which you want to display in iphone and ipad to

Answer (score -1):

The height of UIDatePicker is 162. If you change the following, then the view will be sized properly to fit.

```
UIDatePicker dpPurchaseDate;
dpPurchaseDate = new UIDatePicker(new RectangleF(0,44,this.View.Bounds.Width,162));
```

Also, change its superview thusly:

```
UIView pDateView;
pDateView = new UIView (new RectangleF (0, 0, this.View.Bounds.Width, 162));
```